# Is it possible to remove warning from Data validation while using criteria - list from a range?

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have set a data validation as a list from a range but when I enter a text that does not match the list, I am getting a red warning in the cell.

[image: Snapshot]

My question is: How to use both methods, but avoiding the red warning? How to make datavalidation accept both which is available in range list, and that which is not available in range list, but also keep the dropdown?

Comment: You can ignore it. It won't bother you.

Comment: @TheMaster I feel bothered that's why looking for a solution or alternative way.

Answer (score 1):

Using onEdit(e), I have a script that will compare the value input to the data validation rule and if its not in the list, the error may be displayed momentarily but the value will be replaced with "" which is a valid input.

My data validation is Sheet1!C5:D5 merged cell for a range, Sheet!C7:D7 for a list.

DataValidation.getCriteriaValues() returns an array of objects the first element of that array is an array of the values displayed in the dropdown for a list or a range object.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  try {
    if( e.range.getSheet().getName() === "Sheet1") {
      if( ( e.range.getA1Notation() === "C5" ) || ( e.range.getA1Notation() === "C7" ) ) {
        let valid = e.range.getDataValidation();
        if( valid != null ) {
          let criteria = valid.getCriteriaValues();
          let values = criteria[0];
          if( valid.getCriteriaType() === SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.VALUE_IN_RANGE ) {
            values = values.getValues().flat();
          }
          if( values.indexOf(e.value) < 0 ) e.range.setValue("");
        }
      }
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(err);
  }
}
```

Reference

- [Range.getDataValidation()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDataValidation())
- [DataValidation.getCriteriaValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation#getCriteriaValues())